# Trying to use Crystal 2008 with Visual Studio 2013 and Can't Add References

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I already have Crystal Reports 2011 and the 13.xx assemblies installed. We have an older application that uses 2008 so I tried simply installing the cr2008 12.xxx.x.x runtime, but whenI try adding a reference to the 2008 assemblies they don't show up in Visual studio. Right-clicking references and choosing "add a reference" is only showing the 13.xxxx.x.x assemblies. Is this because I'm running .net 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the most probable reason for that is that you are targeting .net framework 4. Try targeting a lower version of the framework and check if it can see the older assemblies.